# Macro for including headers

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

I work with a legacy code and when I include some headers on linux I have to undef appropriate macros, for example:

```
#pragma push_macro("align")
#undef align

#include <memory>

#pragma pop_macro("align")
```

I would like to create a macro which expands to the above code and can be used this way:

```
include_(memory, align)
```

I can use `_Pragma` instead of `#pragma` inside `#define`but what about with `#undef` and `#include` ?
Is it possible to create such macro ?

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: It is not possible with a macro, but you could create your own include file, e.g. `memory_noaligh.h` that contains the 4 lines shown in the question and replace these lines with a single `#include "memory_noalign.h"`.